# Simple CSS override styling

Tags: css

On that page, the progress bar is messed up:

https://factorbased.com/open-account/

When I inspect the code, it shows padding: 10px to be responsible for this issue.

```
.gform_wrapper .gf_progressbar {
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Why when I write this code it doesn't fix the problem?

```
/* Fix Progress Bar */
.gform_wrapper .gf_progressbar {
    padding: 10px !important;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should try `padding: 0px !important` https://nimb.ws/EWuNB8

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please. Using `!important` is almost always the wrong answer

Comment: @j08691 sometimes using ‘!important’ is the only way to achieve the needed style, for example when the css styles are coming from a third party which you don’t have access to its style.